# Modifying variadic template args C++11

Tags: c++, c++11, variadic-templates

Say I have the following code:

```
template <class ...Args>
DoSomethingWithSubType() { ... }

template <typename T>
void DoSomething() {
  DoSomethingWithSubType<typename T::SubType>(T)
}

struct Foo {
  typedef Bar SubType;
};

Foo foo;
DoSomething(foo);
```

Notes:

- Assume I don't control `DoSomethingWithSubType` (changing it isn't an option).
- I want to make method `DoSomething` generic to accept any number of args.
- `DoSomething` also needs the instance of `foo`.
- When calling `DoSomething` I don't want to provide template args (e.g. `DoSomething(foo, bar)`, NOT `DoSomething<Foo::SubType, Foo::SubType>(foo, bar)`

Overloading like so is an obvious, but verbose option:

```
template <typename T>
void DoSomething() {
  DoSomethingWithSubType<typename T::SubType>()
}

template <typename T1, typename T2>
void DoSomething() {
  DoSomethingWithSubType<typename T1::SubType, typename T2::SubType>()
}

template <typename T1, typename T2, typename T3>
void DoSomething() {
  DoSomethingWithSubType<typename T1::SubType, typename T2::SubType, typename T3::SubType>()
}
```

Is there a way to do this but only write it once?

Comment: Doesn't `template<class... Ts> void DoSomething () { DoSomethingWithSubType<typename Ts::SubType...>();}` work?

Comment: Spot on! Please post it as an answer so I can mark it accepted :)

Comment: None of these DoSomething examples you implemented take instances.  Your example call does.  Your requirements specify instances.  I have no idea what you mean by instance, or your examples are misleading.